# ¿Que deberia usar en este programa, una matriz o un array list 2d o 3d?

Tags: java, array, matrices

Es un programa que gestiona oficinas de coworking (oficinas de trabajo compartidas), el caso es cada vez que se genera una oficina nueva tengo que añadir los puestos de la oficina y si están libres los puestos u ocupados, en caso de estar ocupados añadir el nombre del trabajador.

he pensado hacerlo con un ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList>> puestos = new ArrayList<>();
y trabajarla mediante diferentes metodos-procedimientos, no es posible generar una matriz automaticamente cada vez que se añada una oficina alguna idea de los profecionales.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
// Importamos los paquetes necesarios para hacer funcionar la clase.
import java.util.Scanner;
import oficina.oficina;
import oficina.puesto;
// Clase principal del programa que contiene las instrucciones.
public class coworking {
    // Procedimiento main del programa.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Creamos un objeto de la clase Scanner que nos permita reconocer datos del teclado.
        Scanner datos = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Creamos, un constructor de la clase oficina y puesto para hacer las llamadas a métodos.
        oficina oficinaCopia = new oficina();
        puesto puestoCopia = new puesto();
        // Según la opción del menú almacenada en esta variable se ejecutará un método.
        int opcionMenu = 0;
        // Se ejecuta el menú hasta que el usuario desee salir del programa.
        while (opcionMenu != 9) {
            /*  Desplegamos las opciones disponibles, 
             *  Si la opción elegida está fuera del rango, repetir la decisión.
             */
            do {
                System.out.println("—(•·÷{ Menú de opciones }÷·•)—");
                System.out.println("    1. Asignar nombre a la oficina.");
                System.out.println("    2. Asignar dirección a la oficina.");
                System.out.println("    3. Obtener nombre de la oficina.");
                System.out.println("    4. Obtener dirección de la oficina.");
                System.out.println("    5. Obtener número de puestos libres de la oficina.");
                System.out.println("    6. Asignar un puesto libre a una persona.");
                System.out.println("    7. Liberar el puesto que estaba usando una persona.");
                System.out.println("    8. Consultar quien ocupa un puesto de la oficina.");
                System.out.println("    9. Salir.");
                // Almacenamos la opción elegida en la siguiente variable.
                System.out.print("      "); opcionMenu = datos.nextInt();
            } while (opcionMenu < 1 || opcionMenu > 9);
            // Salto de línea estético.
            System.out.println();
            // Según la opción del menú elegida ejecutamos un método.
            switch (opcionMenu) {
                case 1:
                    oficinaCopia.asignarNombreOficina();
                    datos.nextLine();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    oficinaCopia.asignarDireccionOficina();
                    datos.nextLine();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    oficinaCopia.obtenerNombreOficina();
                    datos.nextLine();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    oficinaCopia.obtenerDireccionOficina();
                    datos.nextLine();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    puestoCopia.obtenerPuestosLibres();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    puestoCopia.asignarPuestoLibre();
                    break;
                case 7:
                    puestoCopia.liberarPuestos();
                    break;
                case 8:
                    puestoCopia.consultarPuestosOcupados();
                    break;
                case 9:
                    opcionMenu = 9;
                    break;
                // En caso de error inesperado, imprimir el siguiente mensaje.
                default:
                    System.out.println("¡UPS, ha ocurrido un error inesperado, por favor inténtelo de nuevo!");
                    break;
            }
        }
        datos.nextLine();
        // Cerramos el objeto de la clase Scanner que hemos creado.
        datos.close();
    }
}

// Indicamos el nombre del paquete que contendrá el conjunto de clases del programa.
package oficina;
// Importamos los paquetes necesarios para hacer funcionar la clase.
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class oficina {
    // Constructor ejemplo.
    public oficina (){};
    // Creamos un objeto de la clase Scanner que nos permita reconocer datos del teclado.
    Scanner datos = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Almacena los nombres de las oficinas.
    List<String> nombresOficinas = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> direccionesOficinas = new ArrayList<String>();
    // Se usa para asignar un nombre de oficina.
    public void asignarNombreOficina() {
        System.out.println("Introduzca un nombre a la oficina:");
        String nombreOficina = datos.nextLine();
        nombresOficinas.add(nombreOficina);
        // Salto de línea estético.
        System.out.println();
    };
    // Se usa para obtener un nombre de oficina.
    public void obtenerNombreOficina (){
        System.out.println("Introduzca el número de oficina:");
        int obtenerOficina = datos.nextInt();
        System.out.print(" es la oficina: " + nombresOficinas.get(obtenerOficina));
        // Salto de línea estético.
        System.out.println();
    }
    // Se usa para asignar una dirección de oficina.
    public void asignarDireccionOficina (){
        System.out.println("Introduzca una dirección a la oficina:");
        String direccionOficina = datos.nextLine();
        direccionesOficinas.add(direccionOficina);
        // Salto de línea estético.
        System.out.println();
    }
    // Se usa para obtener una dirección de oficina.
    public void obtenerDireccionOficina (){
        System.out.println("Introduzca el número de oficina:");
        int obtenerOficina = datos.nextInt();
        System.out.print(" es la oficina: " + direccionesOficinas.get(obtenerOficina));
        // Salto de línea estético.
        System.out.println();
    }
}

// Indicamos el nombre del paquete que contendrá el conjunto de clases del programa.
package oficina;
// Importamos los paquetes necesarios para hacer funcionar la clase.
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class puesto {
    // Constructor ejemplo.
    public puesto() {};
    // Creamos un objeto de la clase Scanner que nos permita reconocer datos del teclado.
    Scanner datos = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> puestos = new ArrayList<>();
    // Visualiza los puestos libres de una oficina.
    void obtenerPuestosLibres () {
        
    }
    // Asigna a un puesto libre un trabajador.
    void asignarPuestoLibre () {

        }
    // Libera un puesto que un trabajador ya no está ocupando.
    void liberarPuestos () {

    }
    // Consulta los puestos ocupados.
    void consultarPuestosOcupados () {

    }
}
```

Comment: tu ejercicio dice que uses una matriz de tipo Puesto....`Puesto[]nombreDeLaMatriz=new Puesto[cantidadDePuestos];`

Comment: Y cuál es el problema con tu código o programa? Tal parece que estás pidiendo opiniones o recomendaciones, lo cual es motivo de cierre de tu pregunta. Te invito a repasar [ask]. Saludos